# To check new running log errors with predefined set of errors

Tags: exception

I have a requirement to code in java, where i have to check running log errors with predefined set of errors/exceptions logged in a file. If any new error/exception occurs other than the one predefined in the file, it should log in to some other file. Any idea or help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are these exceptions in different packages?

Comment: Yes jelle.. all are in different packages

Comment: Most common logging frameworks like SLF4J & Logback allow to create a configuration for a certain package. So you could do something like `com.something.core -> log to xyz.log`, and `org.apache.whatever -> log to whatever.log`. I'd recommend to google information about these frameworks.